# why it is showing a empty repository?

Tags: github, repository, github-actions, fork, github-for-windows

I have created one repository, but it is showing empty.

I just clicked the 'create repository' button and choose public. Then I uploaded a file from local storage.

To confirm it is uploaded, I refreshed the page and found it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow the "[Adding a file to a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/adding-a-file-to-a-repository)" GitHub process:

- uploading a file is not enough
- you need to type a short, meaningful commit message that describes the change you made to the file (At the bottom of the page)
- only when you commit the file would it be visible